# Parsing exception calling "Parse" with "2" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to parse the Date time from +00 into UK format.

This is the script I'm using:

```
$rgName = "product1-website"
$accountName = "product1website"

$dtProvider = New-Object -TypeName System.Globalization.CultureInfo -ArgumentList 'en-GB'

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx | 
    Select-Object Name, 
                  PublicAccess, 
                  LastModified, 
                  @{n = 'LastModifiedTime (Local)'; e = { Try { [DateTime]::Parse("$($_.LastModified)", $dtProvider) } Catch { $_.Exception.Message } } }
```

and this is the error it throws when the date is converted into MM/dd/yyyy:

[image]

How can I just parse and convert the UTC +00 into UTC +1 ?

Comment: It looks like the `.LastModified` property values are [`[datetimeoffset]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset) instances. If so, the only thing needed to convert them to local timestamps (based on the executing system's time zone) is to call `.LocalDateTime` on them; to provide a simple example: `[datetimeoffset]::UtcNow.LocalDateTime`.

Comment: `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-GB').DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` yields `dd/MM/yyyy`, are you sure they use `MM/dd/yyyy` in UK?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, no that's why I got confused myself with the LastModified data type. Because when I convert it using [DateTime]::Parse("$($_.LastModified)", $dtProvider) the month gets swapped or converted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx | 
    Select-Object Name, 
                  PublicAccess, 
                  LastModified,
                  @{n = 'LastModifiedTime (Local)'; e = { Try { [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId( $_.LastModified , 'Central European Standard Time') } Catch { $_.Exception.Message } } }
```

**Result**(using time zone `Central European Standard Time` as `UTC+1`):
[image]